# I just saw this bird outside my apartment. Anyone know what it is? (Texas, US)

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

Saw this bird outside my apartment in College Station, Texas  and have never seen anything like it before! 
It is about the size of a hand.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The climber plant on the wall may be [*Ficus pumila*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_pumila)

Comment: Nice camouflage and funny tail.

Comment: That species is so... special. Unique, beautiful and contrasting, all in one.

Comment: It's also worth noting that these birds are the subject of some [wonderful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKM0P9gWx7k) [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSh9Shgwc5o) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sr_SGkqrrdM)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It is American Woodcock, [*Scolopax minor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_woodcock).

[image]

> Superbly camouflaged against the leaf litter, the brown-mottled American Woodcock walks slowly along the forest floor, probing the soil with its long bill in search of earthworms. Unlike its coastal relatives, this plump little shorebird lives in young forests and shrubby old fields across eastern North America. Its cryptic plumage and low-profile behavior make it hard to find except in the springtime at dawn or dusk, when the males show off for females by giving loud, nasal peent calls and performing dazzling aerial displays.

The [newborns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_woodcock#Nesting_and_young) are even more camouflaged in downs.

References:

- [Audubon](http://www.audubon.org/field-guide/bird/american-woodcock)
- [All about birds](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/American_Woodcock/sounds)

Answer (score 38):

I've found [whatbird.com](http://identify.whatbird.com/mwg/_/0/attrs.aspx) to be pretty good for identifying American birds.  Asking it for grey and brown medium-sized birds that are commonly found in Texas gives 14 options, of which the best match is the American woodcock, as suggested by Sanjukta (which is conveniently early on the alphabetical list!)